# scanner import problem in java netbeans IDE 8.2

Tags: java

so i thought is there any way that i could import a java class for example a scanner class without actually using the keyword "import" in netbeans IDE 8.2?? i tried using the alt-enter way but that didn't work in netbeans.

I have already tried using the alt-enter way but that didn't work.

i tried writing "Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)" between the package name and the public class name and then pressing alt-enter to import the java class but that did not work. the error kept showing class,interface or enum expected.

Comment: You want to use an `import` statement without an `import` statement? That doesn't make sense. Please [edit] your question to write in detail what you are trying to do.

Comment: I think what you're trying to do is to use alt-enter to automatically import `Scanner`, rather than explicitly importing it yourself. If so, please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57747025/edit) your question to clarify

Answer (score 2):

Actually yes you can:

```
java.util.Scanner scanner= new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
```

Also it is applicable to every library.

Answer (score 1):

in Java the import keyword is to avoid ussing the fully quallified name of the class you want to use. so if you dont want to use the import statement you can declare your Scanner this way, in the same position as you do it when you are importing:

```
java.util.Scanner sc = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
```